# Store Axios data into Global Variable

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to store the response data from an axios call into a global variable permenantly instead of it being called every time upon refresh. Since the json file is pretty large it takes the site around 2-4 seconds to load and I want this to only load once on start up

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple choices :

You can use a store, like vuex : https://vuex.vuejs.org/fr/guide/
Which allow your to store datas in an object outside of your component and call il from where you want

If it is a paginated list, you can use a dynamic pagination to load chunks of your datas :
Imagine, you have 10000 items, your user can only see 20 items per page, so just load 5 first pages, and each time the user click on next button, load 20 next elements (It's an exemple, you can improve it at your convinience)

Or your can combine both  ;)